# Existe-t-il des mots spécifiques pour désigner gauche et droite dans une pente?

Tags: demande-de-mot

Dans une pente il y a un mot pour désigner le sens de la descente (aval), un autre pour le sens de la montée (amont), mais en existe-t-il pour désigner, par exemple, "ce qui est à ma gauche quand je regarde vers l'aval"?

Comment: Ça ne me vient pas à l'esprit, mais c'est vrai que ce serait utile. Spontanément, j'ai envie de dire droite/gauche en regardant vers l'aval si la pente est douce parce que je pense à la rive d'une rivière, mais en regardant vers l'amont si la pente est raide parce que je pense regarder une falaise comme un mur depuis le bas.

Comment: Pour un cour d'eau quelconque, on parle de rive gauche et de rive droite, mais il existe sûrement des creux topographiques dans lesquels aucun cour d'eau ne coule (ou ne coule que de façon intermittente, comme les oueds), ce qui rendrait étrange l'utilisation du terme *rive*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

« [**Rive gauche/droite**](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/rive) » s'utilisent en absolu pour parler de la gauche ou de la droite d'un cours d'eau de référence lorsqu'un observateur hypothétique regarderait vers l'aval, sans que l'on doive tenir compte de la position circonstancielle des gens qui parlent, fussent-ils sur l'un des flancs de la vallée et leurs regards dirigés perpendiculairement au cours d'eau, dans une position telle que leur gauche et leur droite s'oriente plutôt dans la direction générale amont/aval que dans celle rive gauche/rive droite.

<sup>Néanmoins, dans ce dernier cas et dans la vraie vie, on utiliserait probablement « ce côté-ci » et « l'autre côté » plutôt que « rive gauche » et « rive droite ». L'écrit, le plus souvent détaché de ce genre de circonstances particulières, peut se contenter de *« rive gauche/droite »*.</sup>

Dans le cas de vallées où aucun cours d'eau ne trouve son lit (le cas par exemple pour n'importe quelle vallée de la planète Mars), ou alors dans le cas de cours d'eau intermittents comme les oueds, le terme *rive* provoque un curieux effet et je ne suis pas certain si la terminologie *« rive gauche/droite »* est de mise. Je ne connais cependant pas d'autres expressions pour définir la chose. Peut-être que « **versant gauche/droit** » pourraient convernir ? Ça semble du moins utilisé parfois, comme [ici](https://guide.zone.ski/sommet-olympia/) :

> Aujourd’hui, Olympia se veut la destination idéale pour les skieurs et planchistes débutants et intermédiaires, grâce à ses grandes pistes larges et peu inclinées, sauf sur le **versant gauche** de la montagne, lequel offre des pistes à forte inclinaison et plus de défis que les deux autres secteurs.

Une autre possibilité si l'on connaît l'orientation générale d'une vallée est d'utiliser les termes [**adret**](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/adret) (versant exposé au soleil, à l'est ou au sud dans l'hémisphère nord) et [**ubac**](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/ubac) (versant ombragé, « exposé au nord » selon les dictionnaires que j'ai consultés, mais on peut supposer qu'il est exposé au sud dans l'hémisphère sud). Près de l'équateur cependant, il semblerait que le positionnement de l'adret et de l'ubac puisse être une fonction du moment de l'année et non une désignation absolue et permanente...

---

Notons tout de même en terminant qu'au TLFi à l'entrée *rive* (liée au tout début de cette réponse), on mentionne aussi un usage de *« rive gauche/droite »* dans la terminologie de l'alpinisme qui ne nécessite aucune étendue d'eau à proximité :

> SPORTS (alpin). *Bord d'un glacier, d'un couloir. On dit « rive droite » ou « gauche », toujours dans le sens de l'écoulement* (SAMIVEL, *L'Amateur d'abîmes*, Petit dict., 1940, p. 239 ds Quem. *DDL* t. 27).

Comment: Je pense que cette entrée du TLFI est le meilleur que je puisse espérer.

Comment: @AnneAunyme Pas aussi naturels et intuitifs qu'amont et aval, j'en conviens. J'ai monté et descendu plusieurs montagnes en suivant de larges plans inclinés où aucun endroit n'était préférentiellement érodé pour créer le lit d'un ruisseau. L'amont et l'aval sont très faciles à identifier, mais les mots pour «à gauche» ou «à droite» dans de telles conditions me sont parfaitement inconnus. Comme mes communications sur le sujet sont presque toujours en présence de mes interlocuteurs, je me contente souvent de pointer le lieu en spécifiant «là» ou «de ce côté», ce qui suffit largement à l'oral.

Answer (score 4):

Si l'on regarde la définition du Littré :

> Le bas du courant d'une rivière, par opposition à l'amont.

Amont et aval s'utilise bien en référence à un cours d'eau. Donc si l'on est proche du cours d'eau, en regardant vers l'aval le côté gauche sera approximativement la rive gauche et le coté droit, la rive droite.

Mais si l'on considère au contraire (ce qui me semble être la question initiale) que l'on est sur un versant de la vallée, en regardant vers le fond de celle-ci : alors suivant le sens dans lequel coule le cours d'eau, l'aval désignera la gauche ou bien la droite.

Il n'existe pas de terme, à ma connaissance pour désigner "à gauche quand je regarde vers le bas de la pente".

P.S.: je serais curieux de savoir si un tel mot existe dans une autre langue. J'aurais tendance à dire que les montagnards n'en ont pas vraiment le besoin car il connaissent probablement l'orientation de leurs cours d'eau et donc amont/aval leur suffit (mais j'espère me tromper!).

Comment: En fait je pose cette question parce que je croyais que "ubac" et "adret" désignaient ces deux notions, mais en fait ça n'a rien à voir.